# Help me calculate my "Meursault / Hours" equivalent?

Tags: weight-loss, cardio, calculation

Here we have Meursault the town,
[image]

and here we have the end result:

[image]

Now. When I exercise, my target heart rate according to [The Walking Site](http://www.thewalkingsite.com/thr.html) is **seventy percent** (that's about 120 bpm for me).

Now, let's say I jog around Meursault maintaining 70%.  And say I do that for **one hour** - sixty minutes.

You often hear things like "if you do such-and-such for 25 mins, that's the equivalent of two slices of wonderbread..." (in other words, you burn up as much energy/fat as you would gain by eating the food in question - or in other words by merely not eating the food serving in question, you've "achieved as much" as the exercise in question).

So my question. If one works out at 70% target heart rate, for one hour, what's the "equivalent" in terms of milliliters of Meursault white wine?

If anyone knows how to calculate this .... **thank you**!!

Of course, I am referring to 2006 Meursault here (that's the choice recent year!) Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Calories/hour @ 120bpm - Calories/0.1 Liter * 7 (1 bottle is 0.7L) = your net Calorie gain/loss**

Running at 120 bpm for 1 hour for someone who's overweight would probably equate to 500 Calories. It depends on your pace and weight whether this accurate.

Assuming the calories in your bottle of Meursault is about 90 Calories per 100 ml = 90*7 = 630 Calories

**500 - 630 = -130 Calories**

What does this tell us? Alcohol is a huge source of Calories, so much that its almost impossible for most of us to exercise enough to compensate for a night of drinking. My advice, if you really want to drink wine, cut your meals down to something light for that day to compensate for the Calorie difference.

---

[Ed] So for the "hour equivalent":  It's about 500 calories for the 1 hour of exercise described. 90 Calories per 100 ml of wine.  Hence, the answer is 500/90

The "white wine equivalent" of one hour exercise at 70% is about:

> about **560 ml** of wine "per" hour of 70% aerobic exercise.

Comment: Ethanol is 7 calories per gram, and that bottle seems to be 13% alcohol, so it's actually ~680 calories (even worse than your estimate)!

Comment: Its balanced out by a poor estimation of his workout @VPeric, but that's an interesting way of calculating it! :-)

Comment: @Ivo -- hi Ivo!  Again thank you so very much for taking the time to show how to calculate this.  Also, I was trying to calculate **"how much wine, "per" hour of exercise..."** (sorry, I should not have mentioned the bottle size - that is not relevant).  So I just added a note expressing it that way.  It's interesting that generally it's "fairly close to one bottle," roughly speaking.  One hour of hard jogging in the vines ... all you've "saved" is drinking one bottle.  Well worth remembering.  Again thank you so very much.

Comment: @Ivo @Vperic an interesting question is, in a sports lab (or wherever) in fact how do you calculate EXACTLY how many calories someone is "burning" during effort?  how is that done, really?  Perhaps it should be a whole other question.

Comment: It should be a whole other question, though I think we already had one. Either way, you can simply estimate these things by keeping track of how much energy you consume and expend. If you still gain weight, there's an error somewhere and you correct your model.

Comment: @joe Basically, measuring it directly is quite hard (you need to measure eg. the heat released by the body), so you'll usually just roughly estimate like @Ivo did and then modify according to results. In any case, unless you are really counting every calorie you eat a small error in estimation will even itself out in the long run.

Comment: @Ivo @VPeric hi guys, I completely understand - IN fact I read all the other existing answers on estimating calories burned during exercise, thanks!  For readers in the future, check out Ivo's answer here: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/51/how-can-i-calculate-calories-burned-during-an-activity  Again thank you so very much.

Comment: Do you have reference for your 500 calorie estimate?